# How do we encourage more people to visit the meta site?

Tags: discussion, meta

It seems like we have maybe a dozen regulars here in meta.  The vast majority of the main site's users never seem to come here or participate here.  What can we do to get more participation on the meta site?

Comment: This seems pretty much how all the meta sites are.

Comment: in fact, we already have an hyperactive meta if we compare to others sites : http://stackexchange.com/sites?sort=newmetaposts&expand=true

Comment: What is the goal? Most of what's discussed here is of no interest to many people

Comment: @DVK Since Meta is where we organize contests and grants, which have prizes and incentives attached to them, I think everyone should see those. Increasing visibility on the grants and contests is something I want.

Comment: @BrettWhite - But then advertise the grants, not META

Comment: @DVK I think having a small, insular group guiding the site is a bad thing.  The more people who are active on meta, the better.

Comment: Any way to help against people slathering on "SPOILERS" in their question title would help

Comment: @Keen - Hey, I don't get to be a member of a cabal that ofren! :)

Comment: I snuck in the back door unnoticed and am now one of the 'in crowd', making the decisions and calling the shots... or not.

Answer (score 2):

Advertise that improvements to the site can be made through meta.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your chatroom is really active, and growing moreso every day. During the group-watches (as "commercial breaks" or the like) make a plug for users to get more engaged in the site by participating in the meta -- mention any ongoing contests or giveaways that may be going on. Also consider *selectively* posting meta questions into the chatroom from time to time; this way, really important site issues will get some visibility without cluttering the chat with a constant feed of, "Why is my question closed?" as metas will often have. (Pasting question into chat worked in DIY, where the meta activity spiked when we started posting in meta questions that we felt were Relevant to Our Users' Interests into the chat directly. I believe DBA does something similar, as well.)

Now that you're a graduated site, you should have access to the Community Promotion Ads. Consider submitting one either to promote a specific giveaway/contest or to just encourage meta participation all around.

Comment: The problem is that most of the users active in the chatroom are the same users active on meta.

Comment: :( Aw, there goes my theory. Still, would I be right in guessing that there's people who aren't regularly in chat who are in the group watches?

Comment: Our recent flurry of general reference debates notwithstanding, we don't have many question closure debates here. We've been feeding all main site and meta questions to chat since the early days of the chat, and [recently decided to continue](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1213). As Kevin wrote, the active chat users are also active meta users anyway.

Comment: But based on my experience in your chatroom, a number of users ignore those bots because they can derail the conversation.